# Cast webelement to webdriver

Tags: appium

How do I convert my `webelement` to Android `webdriver`? Any idea, please?

For exemple:

```
Webelement test=driver.Findelementbyid("test/test/test")
```

I need to convert this `webelement` to driver.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to ?

Comment: It is like asking "How can I convert a passenger to a car". There is no need to do it and it is impossible.
If there is a specific case then please state your situation by giving an example of your code and explain your expected outcome in more detailed way.

Answer (score 0):

No way !!! You can not do that.WebElement is an interface and driver(RemoteWebDriver/AndroidDriver) is a class.

Like @Kristaps said converting webelement to driver is like "converting a passenger into a car". lol :), so don't even think to do that.